# Maximizer 9 - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2010

This may be a stretch as there is likely a vary narrow pool of people that even went down this road. However here goes. Looking at upgrading to Windows 7 from XP and into Office Suite 2010 from 2003. We use Maximizer 9.5 in the office. Having been told that this isn't even possible, I went ahead and put a test box together anyway. For the most part it worked out well as long as I used 32 bit Office. However one small hiccup just came to the forefront.
When trying to insert a merge field into Word file using the Maximizer toolbar add in, nothing happens.
When I installed Maximizer I had to manually relocate maxwin97.dot for the toolbar template, however I'm thinking there must be something else that needs to be moved... The Maximizer toolbar is in Word, but it appears no action is associated when the buttons are selected. Anyone out there been down this road? Is there more files that need to moved to a different path because of the newer Office suite?

Comment: Sounds like Maximizer does not support Office 2010. You will have to get a version that does or hope its updated to support one of the newer versions of Office ( 2007/2010/2013 ) the changes Office 2007 brough were significant.

Comment: Yes it definitely isn't supported and never will be for that version. But just reaching for some work arounds rather than spending the big bucks to upgrade :)

Comment: The way add-ons work after Office 2007 change.  You will be unable to get the add-on to work with a newer version of Office.

Comment: Probably close this thread, as I don't think there is a solution for this short of Upgrading Maximizer!